# dynamically loaded jQuery sporadically throws jQuery is undefined error

Tags: jquery, dynamic

We have jQuery that is dynamically loaded.  That is because we have legacy code that has no master page and all such legacy code was already referencing a common js file when we decided to start using jQuery.  So rather than add a reference to hundreds of files, we updated the existing file to do the following:

```
function loadjscssfile(filename) {
    var fileref = document.createElement('script')
    fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript")
    fileref.setAttribute("src", filename)

    if (typeof fileref != "undefined")
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref)
}
function getRelPath() {
    for (var t = "", n = 0, n = 0; n < document.location.pathname.split("/").length - 3; n++) t += "../";
    return (t)
}

loadjscssfile(getRelPath() + "JavaScript/jquery-1.10.1.js");
loadjscssfile(getRelPath() + "JavaScript/jquery.formatCurrency.js");
loadjscssfile(getRelPath() + "DataValidationFunctions2.js");
```

Now that we have this in place, we sporadically get "jQuery is undefined" errors, usually coming from jquery.formatCurrency.js.  When we don't get that error, the jQuery works fine, when we do, it doesn't work at all.  This is sporadic from the same browser (IE10) one moment to the next.  Since the dynamic code loads both jquery-1.10.1.js ~and~ jquery.formatCurrency.js in the correct order, I would think the code would have had to successfully upload the former before the latter.

We have also updated IIS to turn off both dynamic and static content compression on the JavaScript folder where the jQuery lives as I read somewhere that could cause this issue.  I cleared all cache and still have the problem.

Comment: You need to use callbacks. You're loading the scripts asynchronously, so there's no guarantee that they will load in the required order.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, How do I use callbacks?  Can you give an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're loading the scripts asynchronously, so there's no guarantee that they will load in the required order. Therefore, you should add callback functionality so that you can ensure that the script has finished loading before the next begins.

```
function loadjscssfile(filename, callback) {
    var fileref = document.createElement('script');
    fileref.onreadystatechange = fileref.onload = function () {

        var state = fileref.readyState;

        if (!callback.done && (!state || /loaded|complete/.test(state))) {
            callback.done = true;
            callback();
        }
    };
    fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
    fileref.setAttribute("src", filename);

    if (typeof fileref != "undefined") document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref);

}

function getRelPath() {
    for (var t = "", n = 0, n = 0; n < document.location.pathname.split("/").length - 3; n++) t += "../";
    return (t)
}

loadjscssfile(getRelPath() + "JavaScript/jquery-1.10.1.js",function(){
    loadjscssfile(getRelPath() + "JavaScript/jquery.formatCurrency.js",function(){        
        loadjscssfile(getRelPath() + "DataValidationFunctions2.js");
    });
});
```

Comment: Ahh, I get it!!  Thank you Kevin.  I will work on fixing this now. :)

Comment: This worked great with one tweak: `if (callback != undefined && !callback.done && (!state || /loaded|complete/.test(state)))`  Thank you so much - this has been driving me nuts.  I would up-vote you but I apparently don't have enough reputation yet. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just wait until you know for sure jQuery is loaded, e.g.

```
loadjscssfile(getRelPath() + "JavaScript/jquery-1.10.1.js");

setTimeout(function() {    
    if (jQuery === undefined) {
        console.log("jQuery not loaded. Checking again.")
        setTimeout(arguments.callee, 40);
        return;
    }

    console.log("jQuery is loaded. Continue");
    // Code that depends on jQuery
    loadjscssfile(getRelPath() + "JavaScript/jquery.formatCurrency.js");
    loadjscssfile(getRelPath() + "DataValidationFunctions2.js");    
}, 40);
```